# Why doesn't Robby handover or tell the editor Marty immediately about the possession of the sealed court documents?

Tags: plot-explanation, spotlight

Why doesn't Robby handover or tell the editor Marty immediately about the possession of the sealed court documents in *Spotlight*?

It's only after his lawyer tells Marty, that they have won the case, that Robbie decides to hand over the sealed court documents to Marty. Even Robby's boss Bradlee was not aware of it.

[image: Source: IMDB]